# Problem with a differential function proof

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have an assingment in real analysis. As I'm quite confused with my task, could you give me any ideas/tips or solutions how to get this done?

The task is as follows:

Condition (1):
Let $\sigma > 0$. Then  $f$ is differentiable function in $(a, a + \sigma)$ and there exists a limit (infinite/finite) $$ A := \lim_{x\to  a+}  f^{'}(x)$$

Prove that, if function $f$ satisfies the condition (1) and $f$ is right continuous at a point a, then 
$$ f_{+}^{'}(a) = A $$

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it is a little confusing. You want to assume $f$ is defined on $[a,a+\sigma),$ that $f$ is continuous at $a,$ that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,a+\sigma),$ and that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x) =A.$ The conclusion is then that $f'(a) = A.$

Hint: To show $f'(a) = A$, you need to consider the relevant difference quotients in the definition of the derivative. Apply the mean value theorem to these difference quotients.